# How to compare the date in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm new comer in Database, and I knew some of people had already ask this question before, but mine is a little tricky. Here it is, suppose we have table named Employee like this:

```
Create table People(
ID char(10) PK,
SSN char(15) Not Null,
First_Name char(15),
Last_Name char(15),
Birth_Day date NOT NULL
);
```

And we do some insertions like:

```
INSERT INTO People VALUES('0000000001','078-05-1120','George','Brooks', '24-may-85');
INSERT INTO People VALUES('0000000002','917-34-6302','David','Adams', '01-apr-63');
INSERT INTO People VALUES('0000000003','078-05-1123','Yiling','Zhang', '02-feb-66');
INSERT INTO People VALUES('0000000004','078-05-1130','David','Gajos', '10-feb-65');
INSERT INTO People VALUES('0000000005','079-04-1120','Steven','Cox', '11-feb-79');
INSERT INTO People VALUES('0000000006','378-35-1108','Eddie','Gortler', '30-may-76');
INSERT INTO People VALUES('0000000007','278-05-1120','Henry','Kung', '22-may-81');
```

So my question is how would I find the peoples who are born before ex: January 1st, 1980. I wanna simlply use < or > opeator, but it cannot work in this case

```
SELECT ID,SSN, First_Name, Last_Name, Birth_Day
FROM People
WHERE Birth_Day < '01-jan-80';
```

Anyone could help ?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  You have the correct query.

Comment: Hi JJ E, your query looks correct. Indeed using the < operator is correct here. Can you post any error messages you are receiving, or are you just looking for an explanation of why that is correct?

Comment: < operator works same for Integers and char? I think this could be the problem

Comment: Use strings to compare strings, dates to dates, number to number. Here Birth_Day is of datatype "date" and '01-Jan-80' is a string. by performing to_date('01-Jan-1980','DD-mon-yyyy')/cast('01-jan-1980' as date), you are comparing like to like

Answer (score 3):

You are using a date string and relying on implicit conversion for comparing it with date type.

Use `DATE` literals or `TO_DATE` function instead.

```
SELECT ID,SSN, First_Name, Last_Name, Birth_Day
FROM People
WHERE Birth_Day < DATE '1980-01-01'

SELECT ID,SSN, First_Name, Last_Name, Birth_Day
FROM People
WHERE Birth_Day < TO_DATE('01-jan-1980','dd-mon-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `to_date`:

```
--this is only for testing
with brth as (
select to_date('24-may-85') as Birth from dual
union
select to_date('24-jan-79') as Birth from dual

) 
-- actual solution
select * from brth where BIRTH < to_date('01-JAN-80')
```